# ClickOnce setup.exe doesn't contain Product name and wrong Product version

Tags: installation, clickonce

I'm building installer for Outlook add-in with Publish... action in Visual Studio 2015.
I've set up in Publish tab everything: Publisher name, Product name, Publish version etc.

[image]

But when I check setup.exe it doesn't show Product name and shows wrong Product version.
[image]

How can I make setup.exe have correct Product name and version?

P.S. during installation process product name and version are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Setup.exe don't compiling in build time and it's saved somewhere binary template file. Visual Studio simply adds in template file resources source ClickOnce Application address and it works if you just download single file from server. Here we have 14.0.23107.0 version, and that's mean you have VS2015 and 23107 studio build number. So, unfortunately you can't change it if you use msbuild task for publish.

But you can change it from external application. Just follow this steps:

> 1. Download rcedit https://github.com/electron/rcedit/releases
> 2. And now you can execute it like me shown below:

```
 rcedit-x86.exe setup.exe --set-product-version "2.2.2.2" --set-version-string "ProductName" Myproduct
```

> 3. Result here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hkZI.png

That's all.

Comment: this initially worked for me however it removes Digital Signatures property of Executable which is bummer now and back to square one